# fb:login-button doesn't show

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-login

Recently dealing with Facebook Login Javascript, which I would like to embed into my web page. I have set up the sdk and put the code into my html page. It works previously that I've clicked on the button to test out the login functionality for few times.

However, the login button doesn't even show up on the next day. The code is not changed at all. When I check the status of my registered app status in my developer account, it says it's live and working perfectly.

Below is the simple code of my web page:

```
<script>
  // This is called with the results from from FB.getLoginStatus().
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    // The response object is returned with a status field that lets the
    // app know the current login status of the person.
    // Full docs on the response object can be found in the documentation
    // for FB.getLoginStatus().
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
      // Logged into your app and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please authorise ' +
      'your Facebook account.';
    } else {
      // The person is not logged into Facebook, so we're not sure if
      // they are logged into this app or not.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
      'into Facebook.';
    }
  };

  // This function is called when someone finishes with the Login
  // Button.  See the onlogin handler attached to it in the sample
  // code below.
  function checkLoginState() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  };

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'xxxxxxx',
      cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access 
                        // the session
      xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
      version    : 'v2.7' 
      });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
    statusChangeCallback(response);
  });

};

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

  // Here we run a very simple test of the Graph API after login is
  // successful.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
  function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', {fields:'name,email'}, function(response) {
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
      'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + response.email + '!';
    });
  };
</script>

<div class="section section-about-header">
  <div class="jumbotron about">
    <div class="container info-panel">
      <div class="col-sm-12"><h2><strong>GET STARTED</strong></h2></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="section">
  <div class="wrapper container text-center" style="color:gray;font-size:12px;">
    <fb:login-button data-max-rows="1" data-size="large" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" scope="public_profile,email" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
  </fb:login-button>
  <div id="status">
  </div>

</div>
```

Really appreciate for the time and any help in advance.

Comment: are you trying on a real sever or are you just opening the html file locally? did you check the browser console? please add a testlink.